# SAS PROC JSON program takes too long

Tags: json, sas, proc

I have a sas7bdat file which I am converting into JSON using below code
The files is of 8 GB; However during the conversion the output file appears to be more than 22GB and it takes whole day for conversion.
How do I shorten the time for conversion?
Why is the data set huge after conversion:

```
proc json out = '/...../JSON/output.json';
   export '/.../sas_file';
run;
```

Comment: Why would you even consider using JSON format for 8 Gbytes of data?

Comment: sas7bdat files are typically compressed (assuming you have enabled compression by default). JSON is uncompressed. JSON is not a good format candidate for a file that large.

Comment: We have to read sas7bat files onto pyspark; however we do not have sas integration. SO as a workaround we are considering json format, converting into csv and uploading will take a longer time

Comment: Any other suggestion are welcome

Comment: Would it take longer than a day to write it as a CSV and upload? One other option would be to write the JSON file as chunks in parallel sessions. This can greatly decrease processing time, but you'll need to upload multiple files and combine them at the end.

Comment: JSON does not have a 'header' (metadata) concept.  Every row is rendered as name value pairs "column1-name":"row-i,column1 value" ... "column-N-name":"row-i,column-N value". That is why the output gets so big.  CSV Is probably far quicker and certainly less disk space.  Do you also use coded values and custom formats in the data set?  Are you placing the output on a network share ? Is pyspark on a different machine ?  USB net can sometimes be quicker: write to local file, copy file to USB, copy file from USB to pyspark local drive.

Comment: The sas7bdat is a binary format so everything is stored in binary. However, most SAS shops I have seen do not store compressed (which is an option in SAS that changes the sas7bdat layout). JSON or XML are HORRIBLE formats to use. They are text representations with add'l overhead. CSV may be a decent option.

Why can't you just copy the sas7bdat and read it directly into Python? I think there is a SAS/python library for reading sas7bdat

Comment: See this article: https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2014/01/28/create-zip-ods-package/

Spin out the SAS data into a CSV file then zip it. That will create a binary variant that is readable on the receiving end.

Comment: Thank you all for the inputs; will try converting it to csv file. we do not have admin rights nor sas integration with pyspark

Comment: The SASjs framework uses the following macro for writing JSON, for your use case (not using _webout) you should remove the binary copy step, but maybe it will be helpful:  https://github.com/macropeople/macrocore/blob/master/base/mp_jsonout.sas

Output as ARR to reduce file size (` %mp_jsonout(ARR,myds,jref=tmp)`)